# How to declare a function as real in order to get rid of Conjugate in front of the expressions?

Tags: function-construction, complex

I have a complicated complex function containing some other ones that are real, `f=f(A,B,C,...)` ,where `A=A(r)` and it is real, for example. When I do `Conjugate[f]` I get something like `Conjugate[f]=f*=f*(Conjugate[A],Conjugate[B],...)`, I mean those internal function arent interpreted as real. 
I tried `ComplexExpand` to work with it by assuming that those internal functions are real, but it does not work. I also tried `$Assumptions={A,B,...}\[Element] Reals` at the beginning of the nb, and nothing. 
What I want is to `Simplify` some expressions like `(-I A)(I A)=A^2`, but I only get `Conjugate[A] A`.
Is there some way to declare these internal functions as real, even they are part of a larger more complicated complex function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption should be made on the value of `g[_]`, not of plain `g`. Otherwise, your assumption can be introduced globally through `$Assumptions`, or as a second argument to `Simplify`, or using `Assuming`, all with the same result.

```
Clear[f, g, r]
f[arg_] := a - I arg

Conjugate[f[g[r]]]
(* Out: Conjugate[a] + I Conjugate[g[r]] *)

Assuming[g[_] ∈ Reals, Simplify[ Conjugate[f[g[r]]] ] ]
(* Out: Conjugate[a] + I g[r] *)
```

Comment: You probably meant `$Assumptions`

Comment: @belisarius I certainly did! Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @MarcoB . Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another possible solution which doesn't require you to use `Simplify`:

```
Clear[f, a, g, r]
f[arg_] := a - I arg

Conjugate[g[r_]] ^:= g[r]

Conjugate[f[g[r]]]

(* ==> Conjugate[a] + I g[r] *)
```

This uses [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSetDelayed.html) to make the desired assumption part of the definitions associated with `g`.

Comment: Very elegant! (+1)